# Episerver LinkItemCollection not visible to users

Tags: episerver

We are using PageTypeBuilder to define our PageTypes, on one page we have a property which represents a Link item collection as below:

```
[PageTypeProperty(Type = typeof(PropertyLinkCollection), HelpText = "Test links.", EditCaption = "Test links", SortOrder = 11)]
        public virtual LinkItemCollection PageLinks { get; set; }
```

We can populate this in CMS editor mode with links, save and publish without any errors. We then have a user control that inherits from EPiServer.UserControlBase and grabs the LinkItemCollection property using the below code and binds it to a repeater:

```
var links = currentPage.Property["PageLinks"].Value as LinkItemCollection;
if (links != null)
{
    linkRepeater.DataSource = links;
    linkRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

If I view the page when logged in as a CMS editor this page works fine and the links parameter is populated correctly, however if I view the page as a normal user and not logged in the links variable is always null (although when I'm debugging I can see the currentPage.Property["PageLinks"] is present, and the type is LinkCollection, its just that the Value is null

Is there something I need to configure here, permissions on a specific page type?

Comment: What happends if you just put a <EPiServer:Property runat="server" PropertyName="PageLinks" /> in your user control or template? Does it render a list of links?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely one of the pages in the LinkItemCollection not being accessible by outside visitors. Try accessing the links in the collection as an outside visitor and remove any of the links that are in fact locked from outside view.